# Discord.py Mentioning users that are online and have specific roles

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

so I have recently seen a few discord bots do this and was wondering how to make a discord.py command mention an online user that also has (lets says) a moderator or admin role along with the person who said the command and the channel the command was initiated in.

The idea would be something like this:

User: s.assistance

Mod requests channel:

@ (random moderator or admin that is online)

@user has requested assistance in # (channel the command was run in)

Is this possible in discord.py and how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want remember to `import random`

```py
@client.command()
async def assistance(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(STAFF_CHANNEL_ID)
    admin_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='ROLE_NAME_HERE')
    
    online_admin = []
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if admin_role in user.roles and str(user.status) == "online":
            online_admin.append(user)

    await channel.send(f"{random.choice(online_admin).mention} This user needs your help {ctx.author.mention}")
```

Comment: Getting an error saying 'online_users' not defined, any ideas?

Comment: I changed the variable name last second to make it more clear. did not do it right, my bad . Glad that you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your bot mention the Admin and Moderator roles themselves.

```
client.command()
async def assistance(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    channel = client.get_channel(STAFF_CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} is in need of assistance!\n<@ROLEID>")
```

Comment: No, I want it to mention a random online moderator/admin because I used something similar to that before and about 75% of my staff said to delete it because it was mentioning all the staff.

Comment: Alright, in that case, Abdulaziz's answer should work!

Comment: Ah you put online_user instead of online_admin, just tested it and it now works thank you for your help.